# import Requests Error: invalid syntax

Tags: python-requests

I am having issues importing Requests in Python 3.5. Oddly, this does not happen in Python 2.7.

More specifically, I am using Python 3.5.2 and Python 2.7.13

Here is the traceback:

```
C:\Users\nmehandru>py -3
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC 
v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\nmehandru\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\requests\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "C:\Users\nmehandru\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 47, in 
<module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "C:\Users\nmehandru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", 
line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "C:\Users\nmehandru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", 
line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa, rsa
  File "C:\Users\nmehandru\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\rsa.py", line 14, in 
<module>

  ...
  File "C:\Users\nmehandru\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2097, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File ".\google.py", line 30
    except ConnectionError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Because you are importing libs for python 2. Try to create virtual environment with your python3.5, install your libs there and then import whatever you need from there.

Comment: What is `.\google.py`? Remove **that file**.

Comment: @sehrob: not a `requests` problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks, got it.

Comment: You also removed a whole chunk of traceback, so I can't tell how pkg_resources found it. But it looks to me that you have some `google.[...]` packages installed, and a local `google.py` file is masking that namespace. Because that local file contains Python 2 only syntax, that breaks loading metadata for the `google.[...]` namespaced package. Remove that file and your problem should go away.

Comment: great, thank you guys for the help.